# Splitting of primes terminology doubt

Tags: field-theory, terminology, extension-field

What do we mean when we say that a given prime $p$ splits completely in an algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$?

Are we talking about the splitting of prime ideals into unique factors? And, in that case, we do we mean by "complete" splitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an algebraic extension $F:\mathbb Q$, the ideal $p\mathfrak o_F$ can be written as a product of prime ideals. If the product has $[F:\mathbb Q]$ factors, $p$ splits completely; if the product has only one factor, $p$ is inert. Anything inbetween may happen (not to mention ramification, i.e., the occurance of repeated factors). 
Maybe you have so far considered only quadratic extensions, where there isn't really anything "inbetween" possible?

Comment: Yeah, till now, I was just dealing with quadratic extensions. That's why I had a problem when I moved on higher extensions.